# Nginx 301 Redirect by variable

Tags: nginx, http-redirect

I am setting up a 301 redirect server for the websites I host.  When I get a new customer, I don't want to go edit the domain list in the server block below.  Instead of a hard-coded domain in the nginx configuration, I want to redirect anydomain-here.com to 301 -> www.anydomain-here.com

All domains that are bare (ie domain.com) will be redirected to www.domain.com

```
server {
  server_name domain-requested.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain-requested.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

In the example above, is it possible to change domain-requested to a variable?  This would allow the server to redirect any site that doesn't have a subdomain, such as www.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a map to set a variable if a bare domain was used:

```
map $host $anydomain_here {
    # capture bare domain & store in variable $anydomain_here
    ~^(?<anydomain>[^\.]+)\.com$ $anydomain;
}

server {
    listen  80  default_server;
    server_name _;

    if ($anydomain_here) {
        # redirect if a bare domain was matched
        return 301 $scheme://www.$anydomain_here.com$uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly - I didn't even think of doing it that way!  Thanks for helping and giving me something to learn!

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful! Nginx is fun. There are so many different ways to do things.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of at least one hardcoded domain name with Nginx 1.4.6:

```
 rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.$server_name/$1 permanent;
```

You could abstract that further by putting it an include file, which all server blocks include. You can't do better than that using Nginx alone, because `rewrite` is not allowed to be declared in the `http` context to apply to multiple `server` blocks.

Some other ideas to consider:

- Use a templating system to manage your Nginx configs.
- Many DNS provides provide HTTP redirection services, so their web servers would be the one receiving the request and receiving the redirects.

I have used both approaches above myself.  The downside to using an DNS providers for HTTP redirection is they don't handle incoming SSL requests, but that's only a downside if you were going to buy and install a second SSL cert just to handle HTTPS redirects on the second domain yourself.